# How can I find all the Guids in some text?

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex, guid

I've got a bunch of web page content in my database with links like this:

```
<a href="/11ecfdc5-d28d-4121-b1c9-1f898ac0b72e">Link</a>
```

That Guid unique identifier is the ID of *another* page in the same database.

I'd like to crawl those pages and check for broken links.

To do that I need a function that can return a list of all the Guids on a page:

```
Function FindGuids(ByVal Text As String) As Collections.Generic.List(Of Guid)
    ...
End Function
```

I figure that this is a job for a regular expression.  But, I don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Function FindGuids(ByVal Text As String) As List(Of Guid)
    Dim Guids As New List(Of Guid)
    Dim Pattern As String = "[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-([a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}"
    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(Text, Pattern)
        Guids.Add(New Guid(m.Value))
    Next
    Return Guids
End Function
```

Answer (score 8):

> [0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you grab a free copy of [expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) and learn to build them!

Here's a 10 second attempt with no optimization, checks upper and lower case and creates a numbered capture group:

```
([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})
```

Then you just have to iterate through the matched groups...

Answer (score 2):

There are easier ways to check for broken links.... for example I think http://www.totalvalidator.com/ will do it :D

This could also help

```
static Regex isGuid = 
    new Regex(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

and then

```
static bool IsGuid(string candidate, out Guid output)
{
bool isValid = false;
output=Guid.Empty;
if(candidate!=null)
{

 if (isGuid.IsMatch(candidate))
 {
  output=new Guid(candidate);
  isValid = true;
 }
}
return isValid;
```

}

Comment: That looks handy.  But many pages of this web site require login and have other business rules I must handle.

Comment: Total validator (advanced) will do authentication too!

Comment: I think it is actually the Pro (not advanced) version