# Get all nodes having node.InnerText is of type GUID

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<Step ID="6">
    <ACTION>Object Information</ACTION>
    <CLASS_ID>ControlType.Button</CLASS_ID>
    <UUID>5170c4b8-a949-49ed-bcf5-b0f689b8ec0d</UUID>   
    <ACTION_INFO>0bbde809-83c6-4f69-8b73-d20e193ddb89</ACTION_INFO>
    <REPOSITOR>OK</REPOSITOR>    
  </Step>
  <Step ID="7">
    <ACTION>Object Information</ACTION>
    <CLASS_ID>ControlType.Button</CLASS_ID>
    <UUID>5170c4b8-a949-49ed-bcf5-b0f689b8ec0d</UUID>   
    <REPOSITOR>0bbde809-83c6-4f69-8b73-d20e193ddb89</REPOSITOR>
    <TUID>Handle ,5000(ms),b034879a-ab31-4570-b2f6-bfd650d0ee67,5</TUID>
    <SUBACTION>OK</SUBACTION>        
  </Step>
```

I have to iterate through xmldoc and get all nodes having node.InnerText is of type GUID or if GUID is in between string that too

```
   XMLNodeList l_NodeToAppend = xDoc.SelectNodes("//text()"+"of type guid or guid in between string");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can't be done just using XPath, so we'll incorporate some LINQ and [`Guid.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var guids = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Step/*")
        .Cast<XmlNode>()
        .Where(e => 
        {
            Guid temp;
            return Guid.TryParse(e.InnerText, out temp);
        })
        .ToList();
```

`guids` variable will contain all elements with `InnerText` parse-able to guid.

If you need to find guid in the middle of inner text i.e mixed up with other non-guid string, then your best bet would be using Regex*:

```
var pattern = "[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-([a-fA-F0-9]{4}-){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}";
var r = new Regex(pattern);

var guids = from e in xDoc.SelectNodes("//Step/*").Cast<XmlNode>()
        let m = r.Match(e.InnerText)
        where m.Success
        select m.Value;
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GU6j6S)</kbd>**

*) Many questions have been posted on this topic here in SO. The regex in this answer, for example, is from [How can I find all the Guids in some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644504/how-can-i-find-all-the-guids-in-some-text)

Comment: har07 GUID is in between innertext how should we get that

Comment: `guids.Select(o => o.InnerText).ToList()` is this what you mean, i.e getting list of guid string instead of the nodes/elements?

Comment: your answer is right but one more case if GUID "b034879a-ab31-4570-b2f6-bfd650d0ee67" is in between any string like "abc#$%$%'-#%%b034879a-ab31-4570-b2f6-bfd650d0ee67#$$%kgklsgksgmks" i need that too

Comment: @John in that case, you'll need to use regex... check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks har07 for your answer